# Difference between two program?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

I made a stack class using list-node.
But one works fine, the other always crashes.
What is the difference between two program?
I thimk destructor destroys

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
public:
    int pop() {
        data = next->data;
        auto tmp = next;
        next = next->next;
        delete tmp;
        return data;
    }
    void push(int n) {
        Stack* p = new Stack();
        p->data = n;
        p->next = next;
        next = p;
    }
    virtual ~Stack() {
        free();
    }
    void free() {
        while(next) pop();
    }

protected:
    int data;
    Stack* next = nullptr;
};
int main()
{
    Stack s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    //s.free();
}
```

above  program always crashes..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
public:
    int pop() {
        data = next->data;
        auto tmp = next;
        next = next->next;
        delete tmp;
        return data;
    }
    void push(int n) {
        Stack* p = new Stack();
        p->data = n;
        p->next = next;
        next = p;
    }
    virtual ~Stack() {
    //  free();
    }
    void free() {
        while(next) pop();
    }

protected:
    int data;
    Stack* next = nullptr;
};
int main()
{
    Stack s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.free();
}
```

this program works fine.

what is the difference between the two?

Comment: the difference is that one line is commented out in the upper code. It's quite probable that the `free()` in the above code leads to a "double free or corruption" error. Workaround: use a smart pointer (--you tagged C++11).

Comment: read the code before you comment ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete `tmp` in `pop`, you call `Stack`'s destructor, which in you first code doubles `free`:

Here is the state of your stack after pushing 1 and 2 (with `p1` and `p2` being the new `Stack` objects created in `push`):

```
   |    data       |     next
-------------------------------
s  | uninitialized |      p1
p1 |      1        |      p2
p2 |      2        |    nullptr
```

Now if you destroy `s` like in your first code (ignoring what happens for `data`):

- `s.free` is executed.
- `s.next` is `p1`, so `s.pop` is executed.
- `tmp` becomes `s.next`, which is `p1`.
- `s.next` becomes `s.next->next`, which is `p1->next`, which is `p2`.
- `tmp`, which is `p1`, is deleted, so `p1`'s destructor is called. At this point, we are in the following state:

  ```
     |    data       |     next
  -------------------------------
  s  | uninitialized |      p2
  p1 |      1        |      p2
  p2 |      2        |    nullptr
  ```
- `p1`'s destructor calls `free`, which calls `pop` (because `p1->next` is `p2`).
- `p2` is deleted through `tmp`.
- Back to destructor of `s` with the following state:

  ```
     |    data       |     next
  -------------------------------
  s  | uninitialized |      p2 (dangling)
  p2 |      2        |    nullptr
  ```

In your second code, `p1`'s destructor **does not** call `free`, and does not make `p2` a dangling pointer, so the code "works fine".

You should modify `pop` like this:

```
int pop() {
    data = next->data;
    auto tmp = next;
    next = next->next;
    /***********************/
    next->next = nullptr;
    /***********************/
    delete tmp;
    return data;
}
```

By the way, if you're using C++11, you should redesign your code with managed pointers. Something like that:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
public:
    int pop() {
        data = next->data;
        next = move(next->next);
        return data;
    }
    void push(int n) {
        auto p = make_unique<Stack>();
        p->data = n;
        p->next = move(next);
        next = move(p);
    }
    void free() {
        while(next) pop();
    }

protected:
    int data;
    unique_ptr<Stack> next;
};
int main()
{
    Stack s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
}
```

With `make_unique<Stack>()` being C++14, you can replace it with `unique_ptr<Stack>(new Stack)`.

Comment: I forgot that delete will also call the destructor.

Comment: I forgot that delete will also call the destructor. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In the first, your `pop` is broken - `delete tmp;` recursively deletes the entire substack that starts with `tmp`, not just the top node.
(The destructor of `tmp` will also `free();`, and so on.)
This leads to double deletes.

Your second version leaks memory unless you remember to call `free()` when you're done with the stack.

You can keep the destructor simple and fix both problems:

```
virtual ~Stack() {
    delete next;
}
```

and `free` can be

```
void free()
{
    delete next;
    next = nullptr;
}
```

(There's no need to do a lot of pointer-swapping and element-copying if you're going to throw the result away.)